# Recompile directive based on external variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

currently I'm writing an app, were its necessary to recompile a directive/template once a certain variable has changed. As I am currently in my early steps with developing in general as well as Angular, I didnt mange to pull it off yet.

My directive is as following:

```js
app.directive('slider',function($compile){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl: function(){
        if (tempMovies.length>0){
        $compile('Slider.html');
        return 'Slider.html';
        } else { return 'Placeholder.html';};
        }
    };
});

var tempMovies=[];
```

```html
<slider></slider>
```

The template slider I am using is the one from https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular-swiper which uses the tempMovies array to display certain items. The Problem I'm having is that once you update the slider normally it crashes, so I need to recompile the template once my tempMovies variable has changed.

I was thinking about doing it with a $watch on tempMovies and then triggering a compile of Slider.html but I'm not sure how.

Thanks for any help in advance guys, learning angular has been a blast till now. :)

Comment: Where's your Link function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely want to pass your `tempMoves` variable into the directive:

```
app.directive('slider', function($compile) {
  restrict: 'E', 
  scope: { // pass the variable to your directive
    tempMoves: '='  
  }
  ...
}

// in the markup
<slider temp-moves="someVar"></slider>
```

then in your directive you could apply a `$watch` to the tempMoves variable:

```
app.directive('slider', function($compile) {
  ... 
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('tempMoves', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue != oldValue) {
        // do your $compile here or whatever else it takes to reset the slider
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your fast reply. I think what you mentioned is exactly the thing I'm needing. Just a little thing, in the markup when im passing "someVar" I want to pass a variable from my angular app.js file. Currently im using `<slider temp-moves='{{someVar}}'` but my $watch function doesnt seem to notice the change there. Do you know any solution?